# Many strange redirect loops throughout website

Tags: redirection

***Edit**: I have only just taken over management of this part-completed site, which was copied over from shared hosting install to a VPS. Some configuration might be slightly wrong - I'm not sure, yet*

***Update1**: I seem to have fixed the looping 'Access Denied' problem. The .htaccess, shown below, was in **public_html/** but seems to have been created by Front Page. There was an additional .htaccess in **public_html/temp/** (where Drupal is temporarily installed). Adding RewriteBase /temp to that htaccess fixed part of the issue.*

I seem to be getting some sort of loop happening on my Drupal 7 installation.

<strike>Occasionally on basic pages which don't require authorisation I get multiple lines of 'Access Denied: Please login' .</strike> *(see Update1)*

Pages that are restricted to authorised users should redirect non-authorised (anon.) users to login/register - but at the minute it fails with a redirect loop (ie: if I visit {domain}.co.uk/admin before logging in I fail with a redirect loop).

Also I seem to be having a problem switching between http**s** and http pages. - *I think this is the main issue*

Here are some details:

- SSL configured for www.{mydomain}.co.uk
- Site does not rewrite {domain}.co.uk to **www**.{domain}.co.uk
- Module: **URL alias** disabled (until fixed this)
- Module: **URL rewrite** disable (until fixed this)
- Module: **SecureLogin** was installed but now disabled.
- (update) Module: **Ubercart SSL** causes 302 on ALL pages (may be relevant)

HTTP Virtual Host

```
NameVirtualHost ***.***.***.***:80

<VirtualHost ***.***.***.***:80>
    ServerName {domain}.co.uk
    ServerAlias www.{domain}.co.uk
    DocumentRoot /home/{user}/public_html
    ServerAdmin {user}@{domain}.co.uk
    UseCanonicalName Off
    CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/{domain}.co.uk combined
    CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/{domain}.co.uk-bytes_log "%{%s}t %I .\n%{%s}t %O ."
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/{user}/public_html/cgi-bin/    
</VirtualHost>
```

**HTTPS** Virtual Host

```
<VirtualHost ***.***.***.***:443>
    ServerName {domain}.co.uk
    ServerAlias www.{domain}.co.uk
    DocumentRoot /home/{user}/public_html
    ServerAdmin {user}@{domain}.co.uk
    UseCanonicalName Off
    CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/{domain}.co.uk combined
    CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/{domain}.co.uk-bytes_log "%{%s}t %I .\n%{%s}t %O ."
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/admin/public_html/cgi-bin/
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/www.{domain}.co.uk.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/www.{domain}.co.uk.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/www.{domain}.co.uk.cabundle
    CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/{domain}.co.uk-ssl_log combined
    SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown
<Directory "/home/{user}/public_html/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

<strike>HTACCESS file (site root)</strike> - *now deleted see **Update1***

```
##RewriteEngine On  //temporarily disabled until issue fixed
##RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.{domain}\.co\.uk$ [NC]  //temporarily disabled until issue fixed
##RewriteRule (.*) http://www.{domain}.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]  //temporarily disabled until issue fixed

IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*

<Limit GET POST>
 order deny,allow
 deny from all
 allow from all
</Limit>

<Limit PUT DELETE>
 order deny,allow
 deny from all
</Limit>
```

**HTTPS** Drupal root (public_html/temp/)

```
#
# Apache/PHP/Drupal settings:
#

# Protect files and directories from prying eyes.
<FilesMatch "\.    (engine|inc|info|install|make|module|profile|test|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?    |xtmpl)$|^(\..*|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template)$">
  Order allow,deny
</FilesMatch>

# Don't show directory listings for URLs which map to a directory.
Options -Indexes

# Follow symbolic links in this directory.
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Make Drupal handle any 404 errors.
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

# Set the default handler.
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm

# Override PHP settings that cannot be changed at runtime. See
# sites/default/default.settings.php and drupal_environment_initialize() in
# includes/bootstrap.inc for settings that can be changed at runtime.

# PHP 5, Apache 1 and 2.
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_flag magic_quotes_gpc                 off
  php_flag magic_quotes_sybase              off
  php_flag register_globals                 off
  php_flag session.auto_start               off
  php_value mbstring.http_input             pass
  php_value mbstring.http_output            pass
  php_flag mbstring.encoding_translation    off
</IfModule>

# Requires mod_expires to be enabled.
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  # Enable expirations.
  ExpiresActive On

  # Cache all files for 2 weeks after access (A).
  ExpiresDefault A1209600

  <FilesMatch \.php$>
    # Do not allow PHP scripts to be cached unless they explicitly send cache
    # headers themselves. Otherwise all scripts would have to overwrite the
    # headers set by mod_expires if they want another caching behavior. This     may
    # fail if an error occurs early in the bootstrap process, and it may     cause
    # problems if a non-Drupal PHP file is installed in a subdirectory.
    ExpiresActive Off
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

# Various rewrite rules.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  # Block access to "hidden" directories whose names begin with a period.     This
  # includes directories used by version control systems such as Subversion or
  # Git to store control files. Files whose names begin with a period, as     well
  # as the control files used by CVS, are protected by the FilesMatch     directive
  # above.
  #
  # NOTE: This only works when mod_rewrite is loaded. Without mod_rewrite, it     is
  # not possible to block access to entire directories from .htaccess,     because
  # <DirectoryMatch> is not allowed here.
  #
  # If you do not have mod_rewrite installed, you should remove these
  # directories from your webroot or otherwise protect them from being
  # downloaded.
  RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]

  # If your site can be accessed both with and without the 'www.' prefix, you
  # can use one of the following settings to redirect users to your     preferred
  # URL, either WITH or WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix. Choose ONLY one option:
  #
  # To redirect all users to access the site WITH the 'www.' prefix,
  # (http://example.com/... will be redirected to http://www.example.com/...)
  # uncomment the following:
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
  # RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
  #
  # To redirect all users to access the site WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix,
  # (http://www.example.com/... will be redirected to http://example.com/...)
  # uncomment the following:
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  # RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

  # Modify the RewriteBase if you are using Drupal in a subdirectory or in a
  # VirtualDocumentRoot and the rewrite rules are not working properly.
  # For example if your site is at http://example.com/drupal uncomment and
  # modify the following line:
  RewriteBase /temp
  #
  # If your site is running in a VirtualDocumentRoot at http://example.com/,
  # uncomment the following line:
  # RewriteBase /

  # Pass all requests not referring directly to files in the filesystem to
  # index.php. Clean URLs are handled in drupal_environment_initialize().
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/php/.*$
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

  # Rules to correctly serve gzip compressed CSS and JS files.
  # Requires both mod_rewrite and mod_headers to be enabled.
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # Serve gzip compressed CSS files if they exist and the client accepts     gzip.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.css $1\.css\.gz [QSA]

    # Serve gzip compressed JS files if they exist and the client accepts     gzip.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.js $1\.js\.gz [QSA]

    # Serve correct content types, and prevent mod_deflate double gzip.
    RewriteRule \.css\.gz$ - [T=text/css,E=no-gzip:1]
    RewriteRule \.js\.gz$ - [T=text/javascript,E=no-gzip:1]

    <FilesMatch "(\.js\.gz|\.css\.gz)$">
      # Serve correct encoding type.
      Header set Content-Encoding gzip
      # Force proxies to cache gzipped & non-gzipped css/js files separately.
      Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
    </FilesMatch>
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Try going to admin/reports/status/rebuild and rebuilding all permissions.

Comment: I have just rebuilt the permissions and am still having the same problem.

Comment: I seem to have fixed the looping 'Access Denied' problem. The first .htaccess was in public_html/ but seems to have been created by Front Page. There was an additional .htaccess in public_html/temp/ (where Drupal is temporarily installed). Adding RewriteBase /temp to that htaccess fixed part of the issue.

Comment: UPDATE: there was a custom 403 page (which I had no idea existed previously) which was causing redirect loops. I have updated the PHP code which now correctly redirects to a login page. The only problem I now have is switching to HTTPS and back again (currently loads my new 403 page)